# Converting a linked ASM x86 executable to shellcode?

Tags: c#, vb.net, assembly, x86

I am trying to run some ASM code (it just decrements a number), via C#.  I have a linked file (.exe) and a (.o) win32 ASM compiled file. I've tried to read both of them in bytes and execute it via the standard way of executing ASM in the managed environmnt, however it keeps giving me a System.AccessViolationException.

What gives? I've tried to do some research on memory allocation, but I don't know where my problem lies.

Code:

```
   Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE As UInteger = &H40
Const MEM_COMMIT As UInteger = &H1000

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Private Shared Function VirtualAlloc(lpAddress As IntPtr, dwSize As IntPtr, flAllocationType As UInteger, flProtect As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Delegate Function IntReturner() As Integer

Public Sub Run()

    Dim body As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\MinGW\bin\test.exe")
    Dim buf As IntPtr = VirtualAlloc(IntPtr.Zero, CUInt(body.Length), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)
    Marshal.Copy(body, 0, buf, body.Length)

    Dim ptr As IntReturner = DirectCast(Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(buf, GetType(IntReturner)), IntReturner)
    Console.WriteLine(ptr())
End Sub
```

Edit: If anyone knows how to convert the executable to shellcode. I can simply append the bytes directly to body. I think that's where it goes wrong?

```
section .text
global _WinMain@16

_WinMain@16:
mov ecx,4294967295
myloop:
 dec ecx
 jnz myloop

; Terminate program
 mov eax, 0
 ret 16
```

Comment: Just ask your assembler for a listing and copy the bytes.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do that in NASM?

Comment: `nasm -h` is the help and that says `-l listfile`.

Comment: Thanks. That generated the shellcode, but unfortunately, the code appears to do that with anything more than 3 instructions.

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Executables are not a simple list of instructions. Converting them into a shellcode is generally not trivial. The loading itself is not usually as simple as mapping them into memory. You may want to look into the PE file format or the win32/64 object file format (loosely named COFF).